# How to go to a specific month in full calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I using Full calendar to and I would like to go to a specific month when I select a Month and year on the page.
Is there anything like a go to month function defined or if not, How can i define such function.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the method is called [gotoDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/).

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
```

You'll just have to construct your date object using the values from the drop down, and default the day of the month to 1.